# Java Regex,Empty String be matched

Tags: java, regex, string

I wrote a regex in Java to match sentences containing some string like this:

```
String regex = "((^|([.!?:] ))" + "[^!.?:]*?" + queryStr + ".*?" + "([!.?])|$)+?";
```

Then I use the regex to match my String, see below:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
String content = "Hello World!!!";
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(content);
int index = 0;
while(match.find(index))
{
   index = match.end() -1;
   System.out.println(match.group());
}
```

But the loop never ends, I suspect, because the regex matches empty string. Apparently, my regex includes the String queryStr. So, I am confused with this. Can anyone help me to slove this?

Comment: What's your query string?

Comment: It's random.Here I use "Hello" to test.

Comment: you don't need to specify the index in find

Comment: Your regex has some problem. What exactly string pattern you want to match. Can you add some examples, add more code for `match`, or remove irrelevant code like `content`?

Comment: Well, your regex (apart from `queryStr`) matches the empty string because the first part allows '^' to match, the second has '*' (can match nothing), the `.*?` also can match nothing, and the last part allows you to match end-of-string (`$`). So if your queryStr can match an empty string (e.g. it uses a `*` on everything rather than `+`) then the entire regex can match an empty string.

Comment: If not use index,the previous match will cover my next match within the "." terminator.@AvinashRaj

Comment: I miss the Matcher code, the content is the Source String I want to match.@NguyenDoanTung

Comment: Yeah,but my queryStr(Here,I use "Hello") is not empty.In such a case,why it still match an empty String and index not at the begining?@mathematical.coffee

Comment: Thank you for all your answers.I have solved the problem.The last end symbol "$" I or with ([!.?]), I haven't added bracket,so it is or with all the pattern before.Thus,I got empty String.

Comment: @HuanjianJiang: I guess you were looking for `String regex = "(^|[.!?:] )" + "[^!.?:]*?" + queryStr + ".*?" + "([!.?]+?|$)";`, right?

Comment: That's exactly what I want.@stribizhev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex pattern looks like

```
((^|([.!?:] ))[^!.?:]*?Hello.*?([!.?])|$)+?
```

It contains 2 alternatives:

1. `(^|([.!?:] ))[^!.?:]*?Hello.*?([!.?])`
2. `$`

So, the problem was that you were matching the end of string all the time in a loop.

Make this change:

```
String regex = "(^|[.!?:] )" + "[^!.?:]*?" + queryStr + ".*?" + "([!.?]+?|$)";
```

Now, it will look like

```
(^|[.!?:] )[^!.?:]*?Hello.*?([!.?]+?|$)
```

And `$` will be an alternative to `[!.?]+?` only.

[image]

See [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yW4wS2/1).

Comment: Where is that output from? Looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

Every term of your regex is optional.

To prevent matching blank input, add this to the front of your regex:

```
(?!$)
```

This is a look ahead that asserts the current position is not followed by end of input (ie "something" is following)

Comment: `queryStr`  is not optional.